# Regex match before string comes up

Tags: regex, string-matching

So i have this file of 10,000+ lines of messages from a game server, like so:

> 11.07.23 08:40:16 [INFO] NC: Moving violation: wolfman98 from yasmp
> (-90.8, 64.0, 167.5) to (-90.7, 64.0, 167.3) distance (0.0, 0.0, 0.2)
>
> 11.07.23 10:57:44 [INFO] NC: Moving violation: AKxiZeroDark from yasmp
> (-1228.3, 11.2, 1098.7) to (-1228.3, 11.2, 1098.7) distance (0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0)

The current regex code i have is: `\d{1,4}\.\d{1}`, which matches so far everything in bold:

> **11.07.23** 08:40:16 [INFO] NC: Moving violation: wolfman98 from yasmp (-**90.8**, **64.0**, **167.5**) to (-**90.7**, **64.0**, **167.3**) distance (**0.0**, **0.0**, **0.2**)

Ive been having trouble finding a way to get the part that only says:

> (-1228.3, 11.2, 1098.7) to (-1228.3, 11.2, 1098.7)

before the "distance" word, and without the timestamp in the beginning, and eventually replacing it to end up like this:

> 11.07.23 08:40:16 [INFO] NC: Moving violation: wolfman98 from yasmp
> **(-#, #, #)** to **(-#, #, #)** distance (0.0, 0.0, 0.2)
>
> 11.07.23 10:57:44 [INFO] NC: Moving violation: AKxiZeroDark from yasmp
> **(-#, #, #)** to **(-#, #, #)** distance (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

And a bit of extra information, the numbers can be either negative or not, ranging from 1.0 digit to 1234.0 digits, which is why i need help matching before the word "distance" again.

EDIT: Or even, it would be fine if the entire thing didnt show up:

> 11.07.23 08:40:16 [INFO] NC: Moving violation: wolfman98 from yasmp
> distance (0.0, 0.0, 0.2)
>
> 11.07.23 10:57:44 [INFO] NC: Moving violation: AKxiZeroDark from yasmp
> distance (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly hairy looking regex that extends your number matching regex would be `\((?:-?\d{1,4}\.\d{1}(?:, |\))){3} to \((?:-?\d{1,4}\.\d{1}(?:, |\))){3}(?= distance)`. Let's break that down a little.

It is made up of two groups that are identical to match the two groups of numbers in parens: `\((?:-?\d{1,4}\.\d{1}(?:, |\))){3}`. The regex now allows an optional `-` before the number and which makes the number match `-?\d{1,4}\.\d{1}`. After each number there is either a comma or a paren, so to iterate the number match we need that as well: `(?:, |\))`. That entire beast is then prefixed with `\(` to get the opening paren of the number group. That regex is repeated twice to get the two groups of numbers with the `to` match in-between.

The final bit is a positive look-ahead to ensure that we are matching the number groups that are followed by the word `distance`. That word will not be included in the match, but will have to be there for the regex to match.

I've used non-capturing groups (the `(?: ... )` stuff) because I don't know what you want to do with the captures.

I've tried this out against your two example logfile lines using perl 5.12.2 and it seems to work.

Comment: You can then use this regex to replace the number with hashes by extracting now the matched numbers, replacing the numbers with hashes, and then reconstructing the log line: `perl -ne '/^(.*)(\((?:-?\d{1,4}\.\d{1}(?:, |\))){3} to \((?:-?\d{1,4}\.\d{1}(?:, |\))){3})(?= distance)(.*)$/ && do 
{ my ($pre, $no_numbers, $post) = ($1, $2, $3); $no_numbers =~ s/\d+\.\d+/#/g; print "$pre$no_numbers$post\n"; }'`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to match from the start of the `(` that opens the sequence, to the end of the `)` before distance.

A not-checked, may-be-too-broad regexp could be: `\([-0-9., ]+\) to \([-0-9., ]+\)` but that may match things you don't want.

Comment: You would also need a space between the brackets pairs for it to match, i.e., `\([-0-9., ]+\) to \([-0-9., ]+\)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?:\-|\b)\d{1,4}.\d{1}\b(?=.*distance)/
```

Matches the numbers you want (tested in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use ARGV::readonly;

my $rx = qr/\([0-9,\.\- ]+\)/;

while (<>) {
    s/ $rx to $rx( distance $rx\s*)$/$1/;
    print;
}
```

**Usage:** `script.pl input.txt > output.txt`

Or as a one-liner with simpler regexes. Just remove the first two parens, whatever they contain:

```
perl -pwe 's/ \([^)]+\)//; s/ \([^)]+\)//;' input.txt
```